# Set width of the dropdown asp:MenuItems

Tags: asp.net, coding-style, width, menuitem

I made a Menu in asp.net with different levels. And out of curiousity I would like to know how to set the width for the MenuItems Test1 and Test2.

My code:

```
<asp:Menu ID="Menu1" runat="server" CssClass="menu" 
    EnableViewState="false" IncludeStyleBlock="false" Orientation="Horizontal" Font-Names="Verdana" >
 <Items>
     <asp:MenuItem Text="Test" Selectable="false">
         <asp:MenuItem  NavigateUrl="~/Test1.aspx" Text="Test1" Value="Test1"/>
         <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/Test2.aspx" Text="Test2" Value="Test2"/>  
     </asp:MenuItem>
 </Items>
 </asp:Menu>
```

I searched the net, tried some things but couldn't figure it out. Any simple but working ideas for this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<style>
    .level1
{
    width:500px;
}

</style>

<asp:menu ID="Menu1" runat="server">
             <LevelMenuItemStyles>
                <asp:MenuItemStyle CssClass="level1"/>
              </LevelMenuItemStyles>

        <Items>
        <asp:MenuItem Text="First"></asp:MenuItem>
        <asp:MenuItem Text="second"></asp:MenuItem>
        </Items>
        </asp:menu>
```

Alternative

```
protected void Menu1_MenuItemDataBound(object sender, TreeNodeEventArgs e)
    {
               e.Item.Text = "<div style='width:100px; color:Yellow; background-color:Orange' >" + e.Item.Text + "</div>";
    }
```